# How to bypass custom schema restrictions when opening a link from the browser?

Tags: macos, browser, deep-linking, custom-protocol, custom-scheme-url

When using desktop apps like Slack or VSCode and opening deep links from their own websites, the app gets immediately launched without showing the regular "A website wants to open this application" alert, here is an example URL: vscode:extension/Postman.postman-for-vscode

[image: Deeplink alert]

How can I bypass these custom schema restrictions when opening my own link using a custom protocol from the browser?

Softwares like [Linear](https://linear.app/), run a local HTTP server on the user machine and make HTTP requests to http://127.0.0.1/ to interact with the application but from my understanding that's not what Slack and VSCode are doing.

Any ideas on how I could implement something like that for a macOS application?

Comment: It's the browser and OS doing that.

Comment: Yes, but there is a way to bypass it. I would like to know how slack and Vscode bypass this alert